# Uninstalling or creating multiple gem5 simulations

Tags: linux, uninstallation, gem5

I recently downloaded gem5 and used scons to build a linux simulation with the ARM architecture. That worked, and now I want to make an intel x86 processor. Do I need to remove the existing ARM simulation? if not, can I maintain two different simulations at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

With scons you can build all the architectures you want. It does not matter if you have built any others before